# Pascal compiler not installed on this system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, pascal, gpc

I am trying to run a program, in its description it shows it needs "Free GCC(C) and GPC(Pascal) compiler". I am running 32bit Ubuntu 10.04 and has the package "GPC-4.1" and "GPC" installed.

I have checked my gpc version:

```
$ gpc --version
gpc 20070904, based on gcc-4.1.3 20080704 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 2.1-4.1.2-27ubuntu2)
```

So I believe the GPC is installed successfully.But when I am running the program, it still shows:

```
gcc: /home/source/fmopt.pas: Pascal compiler not installed on this system
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fautomake"
```

What do I miss? Thanks!

Comment: I'm no gpc expert, see if gpc brings its own gcc, try to put the gpc dir first in the path. Afaik the mailing list on gnu-pascal.de is still up (but flow is only an handful per year). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Pascal for general GPC status. Consider migration to FPC, which is still supported.

Comment: What is your version of gcc ? The download site for GPC says that you have to have a version of gcc that matches gpc and they even provide matching bundles of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

The commands above should install all necessary build tools for ubuntu, such as Gnu Compiler Collection (gcc) tools and so on. Whatever is missing on your system, I'd guess there is a chance these commands will fix it.